# Pinescript cant' set variable text at alert?

Tags: pine-script

Can't set the text to a variable?
If do not, need to set the alarm for each text separately.

+
can set variable text function?

Comment: For someone to help you quicker, it's a good idea to include source code / what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create alerts with variable text use the [alert()](https://tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_alert) function.

Comment: thx! this is now updated fuction, i checked .. thx for your comment.